# Not getting role for Box accounts

Tags: box-api

As mentioned in box api 2.0. When I request all users in box enterprise account I am not getting role of those accounts?

I need to collect role as well

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me?fields=role -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

You can specify as many fields as you want via the ?fields=field1,field2,field3 syntax.

Note that in the documentation about the [/users](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users) endpoint there are a bunch of fields that are in green text.  Those are not returned by default, and must be requested specifically by the ?fields parameter.